# href inside document.write expression

Tags: javascript

I have a script that detects if a user is browsing the web application using internet explorer. If they are, I want to write a string and include a link to chrome. My syntax is incorrect.

```
        <script>
        browsername = navigator.appName;
        if (browsername.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
            browsername = "MSIE";
            document.write("You're viewing this page using Internet Explorer. Please use a supported browser ("<a href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/'</a>"Chrome)");
        }
```

Comment: `"<a href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/'</a>"Chrome)"` - waa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not use `document.write` because if the page has loaded it will replace all the content with the string you write.

In the second hand your syntax is wrong, this is the correct code:

```
document.write("You're viewing this page using Internet Explorer. Please use a supported browser (<a href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/'>Chrome</a>)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's incorrect :

```
document.write("You're viewing this page using Internet Explorer. Please use a supported browser ("<a href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/'</a>"Chrome)");
```

By putting " before the  tag, you're closing the first ". You should be escaping the quotes into the string:

```
document.write("You're viewing this page using Internet Explorer. Please use a supported browser (\"<a href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/'></a>\"Chrome)");
```

**EDIT : Didn't even see but why is the "Chrome" outside the  tag? Shouldn't it be  `<a...>Chrome</a>` ?**

Answer (score 0):

I rewrited your script... you had too many issues.

```
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        browsername = "MSIE";
        document.getElementById("ie-warning-placeholder").innerHTML('You\'re viewing this page using Internet Explorer. Please use a supported browser (<a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/">such as Chrome</a>)');
    }
```